# How to disable C++ (intellisense?) errors in VScode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to setup VS code so that I can build my C++ project from a .bat file. However, when trying to experiment and start the build process I'm getting what I assume to be intellisense errors; errors for which I do not receive when building with the visual studio compiler on the command line (cl) through the same bat file. So I was wondering how I can maybe turn off VS code build errors.

I've looked into changing some things within Vs code's settings.json file but there are no options for what I'm looking for specifically, unless I'm looking in the wrong place.

Update:

The suggest duplicate answer does not solve the problem as visual studio 2015 is a completely separate program from visual studio code.

Comment: As it written by this  https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense:
`IntelliSense is a general term for **a variety of code editing features** including...`. This is means that intellisence just only helps you to write code, but it's not able to compile a projects. You should compare the lines given to compiler in .bat file and compiler line given in cmd directly

Comment: Sorry, I meant I also run the bat file in the command line. So the lines in the bat file are what's being executed.

Comment: You can execute the bat file inside the embedded console that vscode has.

Comment: Well I was hoping to be able to use just a quick keyboard shortcut for it instead of having to switch to anything.

Comment: are you getting these errors when running build in VS Code (Ex. with a build task)? Or are they from intellisense? In VS Code's Cpptools extension, intellisense and build are configured separately and configuration needs to be kept in sync manually. Do you really want to disable intelliSense, or do you want to fix it? Fixing it seems like the smarter option to me. If you actually want to disable it, then use the `C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine` setting. see also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/faq-cpp#_how-do-i-get-intellisense-to-work-correctly and https://stackoverflow.com/a/76784622