# Difference in usage of c_cpp_properties/launch/tasks.json and CMakeLists.txt files when using VS Code?

Tags: c++, json, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm new to C++ and VS Code. When I follow some VS Code tutorials to create a `.cpp` file, the `.vscode` folder is created automatically and contains some `.json` files. Also, `CMakeLists.txt` is included at the top level of my project's `src` directory.

I know `CMakeLists.txt` is used to generate `C++` executables. However, without setting `CMakeLists.txt`, `main.cpp` can also be executed based on `.json` files. So I am confused about the difference between `.json` and `CMakeLists.txt` file usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use CMake (your CMakeLists.txt project config), then you'll have to use some other feature, such as just [the cpptools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools) without the CMake integration, where IntelliSense is configured using .vscode/[c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) file, or some other config if you are using a different IntelliSense extension such as the clangd one, build is typically done using [a build task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) (.vscode/tasks.json), and debug is usually done with [a launch configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) (.vscode/launch.json).

If you want more info on non-CMake setup things, see [the related docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp). For CMake + VS Code, see [the docs for the CMake tools extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/README.md).

If you take the CMake route, the only cpptools extension-related setting you should need to set is [`configurationProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference). Build would be handled by the `CMake: Build` command (provided by the CMake Tools extension) instead of a build task, and debug should be handled by the `CMake: Debug` command instead of a launch configuration (although I suppose you could still opt to go that route if you wanted, or use the `cmake.debugConfig` setting). Problem detection will be build-diagnostic-based, so you'll need to rebuild to "refresh" problem detection for things like error squiggles in the editor.